# Problem while installing random in Python

Tags: software-installation, pip, python-2.7

I am using python 2.7.4 and having a problem while  running `pip install random`. It comes up with this error:

```
Collecting random
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement random (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for random
```

Can anyone help me out in this matter?

Results of `pip install -vvv random # verbose output` :

```
File "c:\users\support-ihsan\app\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\req\req_install.py", line 307, in populate_link self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade) 

File "c:\users\support-ihsan\app\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\index.py", line 533, in find_requirement 'No matching distribution found for %s' % req DistributionNotFound: No matching distribution found for random
```

Comment: Those look like Windows file paths - are you using Ubuntu at all?

Answer (score 1):

**This mean that there no package with name random .**

Also random module should be present by default . Cause this code works fine on machine with python2

```
  import random
  num = random.randint(10,20)
  print (num)
```

And I am too getting the same error when I type this command

```
pip install random
```

Comment: what should i do to rectify this error

Comment: Your code works on my computer without installing anything first.

Comment: @karel That is my point . There no need to install anything

Comment: @ihsansaleem There in nothing to do. just import random in your code and start coding .

Comment: @ SmitTheLastFirefoxUser
do i need to downgrade my python version?

Comment: @ihsansaleem There is **NO NEED TO DO ANYTHING**  bro !!Your Python is working correctly . You can start coding without any need of installing anything . Also you are already on too old version of python .

Comment: @SmitTheLastFirefoxUser, i will

Comment: @SmitTheLastFirefoxUser, accepted

Comment: @ihsansaleem xD , you have you to press that green button dude

Comment: @SmitTheLastFirefoxUser, kindly check facing error File "file_downloader.py", line 1, in <module>
    import urllib.request
ImportError: No module named request

Comment: @ihsansaleem ok, but First tell me why I am getting this error in main.cpp file :-  `(.text+0x20): undefined reference to 'main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: @SmitTheLastFirefoxUser,you put me in trouble sorry i am new into python and learning

Comment: @ihsansaleem You are making cry dude .pls find some good book for python

Comment: SmitTheLastFirefoxUser, suggest any book which will cover the basics of python 2 and 3.Secondly,could you please help me out on that specific problem which i mentioned above

Comment: @ihsansaleem https://docs.python.org/3/index.html . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652074/importerror-no-module-named-request

Comment: SmitTheLastFirefoxUser,Thanks Man really appreciated!!